# Not able to connect to DB in php with mariadb gssapi, authentication method unknown to client

Tags: php, xampp, mariadb, windows-authentication, gssapi

I am trying to auth users with gssapi using mariadb gssapi plugin in php on a local installation with xampp. I have set up xampp and a local installation which works. Now i want to connect to the db by using the windows ldap user and gssapi authentication.

the problem was somehow discuessed here, but without any results:
[GSSAPI-Auth with PHP to MariaDB (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50061026/gssapi-auth-with-php-to-mariadb-windows)

the gssapi authentication for the mariadb seems to work. I created a user in phpmyadmin with authentication method = gssapi. In the CLI i am able to connect, see picture below:

[Successful mysql connect with domain user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRBmL.png)

now when trying to connect with

```
if (($dbcon=mysqli_connect("localhost","$mysql_userid","$password"))===FALSE) {
    exit("4:Login process failed while connecting to database");
    echo "Debug-Fehlermeldung: " . mysqli_connect_error . PHP_EOL;
}else{
    $auth_result=TRUE;
}
```

i am getting the following error:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [auth_gssapi_client] in C:\xampp\htdocs\oa5-maria\trunk\login.php on line 82

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client in C:\xampp\htdocs\oa5-maria\trunk\login.php on line 82
4:Login process failed while connecting to database
```

I have set the default-authentication-plugin=gssapi in the my.ini file. But i have no idea if this is the correct approach.

Do you have any suggestions to solve that problem?

This is my my.ini file:

```
# Example MySQL config file for small systems.
#
# This is for a system with little memory (<= 64M) where MySQL is only used
# from time to time and it's important that the mysqld daemon
# doesn't use much resources.
#
# You can copy this file to
# C:/xampp/mysql/bin/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options (in this
# installation this directory is C:/xampp/mysql/data) or
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
# If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
# with the "--help" option.

# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
# password       = your_password 
port=3306
socket="C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"


# Here follows entries for some specific programs 

# The MySQL server
default-character-set=utf8mb4
[mysqld]
port=3306
socket="C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir="C:/xampp/mysql"
tmpdir="C:/xampp/tmp"
datadir="C:/xampp/mysql/data"
pid_file="mysql.pid"
# enable-named-pipe
key_buffer=16M
max_allowed_packet=200M
sort_buffer_size=512K
net_buffer_length=8K
read_buffer_size=256K
read_rnd_buffer_size=512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size=8M
log_error="mysql_error.log"
#neu für authentifizierung
default-authentication-plugin=gssapi

# Change here for bind listening
# bind-address="127.0.0.1" 
# bind-address = ::1          # for ipv6

# Where do all the plugins live
plugin_dir="C:/xampp/mysql/lib/plugin/"

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
# 
# commented in by lampp security
#skip-networking
#skip-federated

# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
# log-bin deactivated by default since XAMPP 1.4.11
#log-bin=mysql-bin

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id   =1

# Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)
#
# To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
# two methods :
#
# 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
#    the syntax is:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
#    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
#
#    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
#    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
#
#    Example:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
#
# OR
#
# 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
#    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
#    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
#    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
#    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
#    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
#    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
#    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
#    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
#
# required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
# (and different from the master)
# defaults to 2 if master-host is set
# but will not function as a slave if omitted
#server-id       = 2
#
# The replication master for this slave - required
#master-host     =   <hostname>
#
# The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
# to the master - required
#master-user     =   <username>
#
# The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
# the master - required
#master-password =   <password>
#
# The port the master is listening on.
# optional - defaults to 3306
#master-port     =  <port>
#
# binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
#log-bin=mysql-bin


# Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
#tmpdir = "C:/xampp/tmp"
#log-update = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname

# Uncomment the following if you are using BDB tables
#bdb_cache_size = 4M
#bdb_max_lock = 10000

# Comment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#skip-innodb
innodb_data_home_dir="C:/xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir="C:/xampp/mysql/data"
#innodb_log_arch_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
## You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
## of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size=16M
## Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size=5M
innodb_log_buffer_size=8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=50

## UTF 8 Settings
#init-connect=\'SET NAMES utf8\'
#collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
#character_set_server=utf8
#skip-character-set-client-handshake
#character_sets-dir="C:/xampp/mysql/share/charsets"
sql_mode=NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
log_bin_trust_function_creators=1

character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci
[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet=16M

[mysql]
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer=20M
sort_buffer_size=20M
read_buffer=2M
write_buffer=2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer=20M
sort_buffer_size=20M
read_buffer=2M
write_buffer=2M

[mysqlhotcopy]

lower_case_table_names=0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between your client and PHP is, that the client is linked against libmariadb (and is therefore able to load the auth_gssapi_plugin, while mysqli is either linked against libmysql or PHP's internal mysqlnd driver.

Beside Kerberos/GSSAPI MariaDB also provides ed25519 and pam authentication (via dialog plugin) which is not supported by libmysql and mysqlnd.

Building ext/mysqli against MariaDB Connector/C unfortunately doesn't work and recent pull requests which fixed that problem were rejected.

Comment: thanks for the info. I am not sure if i understood this correctly. Does that mean that i have to try to use e.g. pam auth to get this to work? Or is there any other way to connect to the DB with LDAP auth?

Comment: Afaik LDAP authentication is only supported by MySQL enterprise server/client. You can just omit the default_authentication_plugin in your configuration and default mysql_native_password will be used.

Comment: But i am not using mysql, i am using mariadb. Thats why we are planning to switch from mysql to mariadb. I cannot be the first one who tries to use a php application with a mariadb to auth via ldap, am i?

Comment: you already wrote in qour question, that you are  using MariaDB. Was there anything unclear why you can't use these authentication methods with PHP  in my answer?

Comment: Wasn't sure if your answer was a clear "No", but i understand now that it is not possible. Thanks anyway. Before i try to investigage some other ways, to you have any suggestions for me? Is it possible with a postgresql database? I know ther is the pg_pconnect function in php, but does this work with with ldap auth users in a postgresql db?